# postgres SQL use returning values to update another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-9.6

Apologies if this is a duplicate (and/or trivial) - I haven't been able to search well owing to unfamiliarity with SQL in general.

In plain English what I want to do:

I have a table `table1` for which some fraction of the `matched_id` column is `NULL`. For these rows I wish to create a row in a `table2` using values `val1` and `val2` from the `table1` row, and then return the `id`s of the newly-created rows in `table2` to update the `matched_id` values in `table1`.

My query attempt thus far creates the new rows in `table2` for the entries I need, but the `matched_id` value of the rows in `table1` are all set to the same value (the value from the first insertion I believe), instead of their corresponding row in `table2`:

```
WITH new_ids AS (
    INSERT INTO table2 (val1, val2) SELECT val1, val2
    FROM table1 WHERE matched_id IS NULL RETURNING id)
UPDATE table1 SET matched_id = new_ids.id 
FROM new_ids 
WHERE matched_id IS NULL
```

Comment: What is `corresponding row in table2`? Your update statement does not contain any condition about *how* to associate the table1-target-rows with the returned value(s) from the insert-CTE.

Comment: Right, it would be the row that is created in `table2` that uses the values from `table1` (i.e. `val1`, `val2`, say) - I was thinking that if I get a returned list of ids from these insertions, their order would remain the same if I then use them to update `table1` with the same `where` condition. As I say, very much new into SQL so I may be way off. I suppose the match could be on `table1.val1 = table2.val1` ditto `val2`.

Comment: Exactly. Just try it! (you should add the other fields to the `RETURNING...` line, too, or use `RETURNING *`)

Comment: I don't understand something what the hall is matched_id in your structure? You want to update it to id from inserting into table2 but it looks like it will be nothing more then table1.id then. If so why not just "UPDATE table1 SET matched_id = id 
FROM new_ids 
WHERE matched_id IS NULL" ?!?

Comment: The insertions into `table2` will obtain an (pk) id from a sequence upon creation, this will not match `table1.id`. `table1.matched_id` is a way to find which row was created in `table2` - these being created as a result of not finding an existing matching row previously (i.e. where `matched_id is NULL`).

Comment: @wildplasser - thanks I think matching on `val1` and `val2` in the final `WHERE` seems to have cracked it. I will just double check. If you want to put it as an answer I will mark as correct.